I want to write a function for React native datepicker so that i can restrict user to select to select "FromDate" higher than "ToDate" and vice-versa
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
const [openToDatePicker, setOpenToDatePicker] = useState(false);
const [openFromDatePicker, setOpenFromDatePicker] = useState(false);
const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState('');
const [toDate, setToDate] = useState('');

const pastDate = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  if (toDate) {
    toDate > fromDate;
  }
  const oneMonthBefore = new Date(today);
  oneMonthBefore.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1);
  return oneMonthBefore;
};

<DatePicker
modal
open={openFromDatePicker || openToDatePicker}
date={date}
maximumDate={
  new Date(
  `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`
        )
    }
    minimumDate={pastDate()}
    mode="date"
    onConfirm={(selectedDate: any) => {
        if (openFromDatePicker) {
            setOpenFromDatePicker(false);
            setFromDate(selectedDate);
            setFromDateFilter(true);
        } else {
            setOpenToDatePicker(false);
            setToDate(selectedDate);
            setToDateFilter(true);
        }
    }}
    onCancel={() => {
        setOpenFromDatePicker(false);
        setOpenToDatePicker(false);
    }}
/>

In this problem, there are four scenarios:

First Scenario: User can select up to one month ago date from the current date. (NOTE: This is already done).

Second Scenario: User can't select a future date, meaning the user is eligible to select dates up to the current date. (NOTE: This is already done).

Third Scenario: If the user selects "fromDate", then I have to restrict the user so that they can't select "toDate" lower than fromDate. (For example, if the user selects "fromDate" as 14/06/24, the user must select "toDate" higher than or equal to 14/06/24. (NOTE: Help me to write this logic).

Fourth Scenario: If the user selects "toDate", then I have to restrict the user so that they can't select "fromDate" higher than toDate. (For example, if the user selects "toDate" as 16/06/24, the user must select "fromDate" lower than or equal to 16/06/24). (NOTE: Help me to write this logic).


